# Filter en angular js (ionic framework urlRouter provider)

Tags: angularjs, ionic, angular-directivas

Estoy consumiendo un web services el cual me retorna un json, Lo que estoy haciendo es en primer instancia poner una lista de cada objeto con su contenido e id, Cuando doy click en un item utilizo parametros por url y hago que ingrese por id ya que es unico su valor, pero tengo un error la verdad nose que sera porque no me muestra ningun dato.

NOTA: Cuando consumo el json localmente si me arroja datos al entrar en cada objeto PERO cuando lo consumo al webservice no me muestra nada espero y me puedan guiar en esto. A continuacion comparto mis archivos

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "responsable": "SIC",
    "tipo": "TITULACION",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "modalidad": "PRESENCIAL",
    "componente": {
      "nombre": "METODOLOGIAS AGILES",
      "guid": "2d25d627-6440-0050-e053-ac10360dd136",
      "codigo": "PRE-TNCCO210",
      "subcomponente": {},
      "paralelo": {
        "nombre": "A",
        "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b6-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
        "horario": {
          "docente": {
            "guid": "a7c2dd51-1865-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
            "identificacion": "0921250601001",
            "nombre": ""
          },
          "registro": {
            "id": 1094,
            "estado": "VALIDADO",
            "contenido": "\u003cp\u003eTema 1.  Fundamentos de las metodologías ágiles\u003cbr /\u003e1.1. Modelos de proceso de desarrollo software\u003cbr /\u003e1.2. El Movimiento ágil\u003cbr /\u003e1.3. Metodologías ágiles de desarrollo\u003cbr /\u003e1.4. Metodologías ágiles versus tradicionales\u003c/p\u003e/nForma de evaluación y características de la materia.",
            "id_contenido_plan": 80989,
            "fecha_clase": "05-04-2016"
          },
          "tipo": "CLASE",
          "parte": "TEORÍA",
          "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b2-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
          "dia": "MARTES",
          "aula": "226",
          "hora_inicio": "07:30:00",
          "hora_fin": "10:00:00"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "responsable": "SIC",
    "tipo": "TITULACION",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "modalidad": "PRESENCIAL",
    "componente": {
      "nombre": "METODOLOGIAS AGILES",
      "guid": "2d25d627-6440-0050-e053-ac10360dd136",
      "codigo": "PRE-TNCCO210",
      "subcomponente": {},
      "paralelo": {
        "nombre": "A",
        "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b6-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
        "horario": {
          "docente": {
            "guid": "a7c2dd51-1865-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
            "identificacion": "0921250601001",
            "nombre": ""
          },
          "registro": {
            "id": 1095,
            "estado": "VALIDADO",
            "contenido": "\u003cp\u003eTema 1.  Fundamentos de las metodologías ágiles\u003cbr /\u003e1.1. Modelos de proceso de desarrollo software\u003cbr /\u003e1.2. El Movimiento ágil\u003cbr /\u003e1.3. Metodologías ágiles de desarrollo\u003cbr /\u003e1.4. Metodologías ágiles versus tradicionales\u003c/p\u003e",
            "id_contenido_plan": 80989,
            "fecha_clase": "12-04-2016"
          },
          "tipo": "CLASE",
          "parte": "TEORÍA",
          "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b2-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
          "dia": "MARTES",
          "aula": "226",
          "hora_inicio": "07:30:00",
          "hora_fin": "10:00:00"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "responsable": "SIC",
    "tipo": "TITULACION",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "modalidad": "PRESENCIAL",
    "componente": {
      "nombre": "METODOLOGIAS AGILES",
      "guid": "2d25d627-6440-0050-e053-ac10360dd136",
      "codigo": "PRE-TNCCO210",
      "subcomponente": {},
      "paralelo": {
        "nombre": "A",
        "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b6-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
        "horario": {
          "docente": {
            "guid": "a7c2dd51-1865-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
            "identificacion": "0921250601001",
            "nombre": ""
          },
          "registro": {
            "id": 4629,
            "estado": "VALIDADO",
            "contenido": "\u003cp\u003eTema 2. Ejemplos de metodologías ágiles\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp\u003e2.1. Scrum\u003cbr /\u003e2.2. Kanban\u003c/p\u003e",
            "id_contenido_plan": 80992,
            "fecha_clase": "19-04-2016"
          },
          "tipo": "CLASE",
          "parte": "TEORÍA",
          "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b2-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
          "dia": "MARTES",
          "aula": "226",
          "hora_inicio": "07:30:00",
          "hora_fin": "10:00:00"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "responsable": "SIC",
    "tipo": "TITULACION",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "modalidad": "PRESENCIAL",
    "componente": {
      "nombre": "METODOLOGIAS AGILES",
      "guid": "2d25d627-6440-0050-e053-ac10360dd136",
      "codigo": "PRE-TNCCO210",
      "subcomponente": {},
      "paralelo": {
        "nombre": "A",
        "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b6-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
        "horario": {
          "docente": {
            "guid": "a7c2dd51-1865-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
            "identificacion": "0921250601001",
            "nombre": ""
          },
          "registro": {
            "id": 6636,
            "estado": "VALIDADO",
            "contenido": "\u003cp\u003eTema 2. Ejemplos de metodologías ágiles\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp\u003e2.1. Scrum\u003cbr /\u003e2.2. Kanban\u003c/p\u003e",
            "id_contenido_plan": 80992,
            "fecha_clase": "26-04-2016"
          },
          "tipo": "CLASE",
          "parte": "TEORÍA",
          "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b2-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
          "dia": "MARTES",
          "aula": "226",
          "hora_inicio": "07:30:00",
          "hora_fin": "10:00:00"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "responsable": "SIC",
    "tipo": "TITULACION",
    "guid": "a7c2dd58-eb27-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
    "nivel": "PREGRADO",
    "modalidad": "PRESENCIAL",
    "componente": {
      "nombre": "METODOLOGIAS AGILES",
      "guid": "2d25d627-6440-0050-e053-ac10360dd136",
      "codigo": "PRE-TNCCO210",
      "subcomponente": {},
      "paralelo": {
        "nombre": "A",
        "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b6-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
        "horario": {
          "docente": {
            "guid": "a7c2dd51-1865-004e-e043-ac10360d004e",
            "identificacion": "0921250601001",
            "nombre": ""
          },
          "registro": {
            "id": 6637,
            "estado": "VALIDADO",
            "contenido": "\u003cp\u003e*  Evaluación capítulos 1 y 2.\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e*  Tema 3. Especificación de requisitos\u003cbr /\u003e    3.1. Concepto y especificación de historias de usuario\u003cbr /\u003e    3.2. Buenas prácticas para la captura de historias de usuario\u003c/p\u003e",
            "id_contenido_plan": 80994,
            "fecha_clase": "03-05-2016"
          },
          "tipo": "CLASE",
          "parte": "TEORÍA",
          "guid": "2d2759ee-c7b2-00ce-e053-ac10360d45c9",
          "dia": "MARTES",
          "aula": "226",
          "hora_inicio": "07:30:00",
          "hora_fin": "10:00:00"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

APP.js el error lo tengo en la vista tabs.ContEdicionTuto

```
.state('tabs.CompDocente', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/componentes',
      views:{
        'componentes-tab':{
          templateUrl:'templates/CompDocente.html',
          controller:'DocenteCtrl'
        }
      }
    })    
    .state('tabs.ListaTutoDocente', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/componentes/:nom_coe',
      views:{
        'componentes-tab':{
          templateUrl:'templates/ListaTutoDocente.html',
          controller:'DocenteCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.CrearTutoria', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/componentes/:nom_coe/:nombre',
      views:{
        'componentes-tab':{
          templateUrl:'templates/CrearTutoria.html',
          controller:'DocenteCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.ContEdicionTuto', {
      cache: false,
      url:'/componentes/:Nom_coe/EdicionTutorias/:id',
      views:{
        'componentes-tab':{
          templateUrl:'templates/ContEdicionTuto.html',
          controller:'DocenteCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

Controllers.js

```
//TRAER REGISTROS CREADOS para ello se llama al MostrarRegistros
    MostrarRegistros.servicioMostrarRegistros($scope.idCe).success(function(data){
      $scope.datosTuto=data;
      $scope.Nom_coe = $scope.nom_coe;
      $scope.id=$state.params.id;
      $scope.cont=$scope.datosTuto.length;// contador que muestra el # de registros creados  
    })
    //FIN TRAER REGISTROS CREADOS
```

ListaTutoDocente.html

```
<div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-divider" style="text-align:center">
          <i class="ion-ios-compose"></i>
          Tutorías Creadas
        </div>
        <div class="list card" ng-repeat="i in datosTuto | filter:busqueda">
          <a class="item" href="#/Gtuto/componentes/{{Nom_coe}}/EdicionTutorias/{{i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.id}}">
            <h2><strong>{{i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.contenido}}</strong></h2>
            <h5>ID: {{i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.id}}</h5>
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ContEdicionTuto.html Muestro la informacion del objeto clickeado

```
<ion-view  view-title="Resumen de la tutoría creada">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-item type="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="i in datosTuto |filter: {id:id}">
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="item item-toggle">
            ID:<br>{{i.componente.paralelo.horario.registro.id}}
            <label class="toggle toggle-dark">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="editar">
               <div class="track">
                 <div class="handle"></div>
              </div>
            </label>
        </li>
      </ul>     
    </ion-item> 
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

En esta vista no se porque no se me muestra la informacion que deseo repito cuando lo hago de forma local si me trae datos pero cuando consumo al servicio web puedo mostrar en la lista los objetos pero al clickear no me muestra la informacion

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Así a ojo, el problema parece que está en tu backend. Supongo que tu servicio `MostrarServicios` hace una llamada externa al backend y devuelve un JSON como el que estás enseñando arriba del todo.

Answer (score 2):

No estoy del todo seguro, pero creo que tu problema es que estás llamando mal a los resultados que quieres filtrar.

En tu controlador, cambia el parámetro por `res` (de response) para evitar hacernos un lío, y en `$scope.datosTuto` accede a `res.data`. El servicio te devolverá un objeto JavaScript, que si imprimes por consola verás que dentro tiene un objeto llamado `data`, que es el que nos interesa.

Por otro lado, no uses `.success()`, está deprecated (Angular 1.5 en adelante), en su lugar usa `.then();` y `.catch()`, que te hacen las veces de try-catch y ayudan a depurar mejor el código.

```
MostrarRegistros.servicioMostrarRegistros($scope.idCe)
    .then(
      function(res){
        $scope.datosTuto = res.data;
        $scope.Nom_coe = $scope.nom_coe;
        $scope.id = $state.params.id;
        $scope.cont = $scope.datosTuto.length;
      }
    )
    .catch(
      function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
     )
```

En tu vista veo el siguiente error: no uses filtros en `ng-repeat`. Y en lugar de usar `<a href=function>Funcion</a>`, usa la directiva [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) para acceder a la función que te interese, pasándole como parámetro a esta el ID que necesites.

No veo más errores, al menos a priori. ¡Suerte!